# Is there a way to schedule the shutdown of Selenium nodes without breaking tests?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, automated-tests, selenium-grid

I have set up a Selenium Grid with 3 different servers running nodes as windows services. I need to restart those machines regularly to avoid memory leaks and under performance. To do this I need to schedule a job to shutdown the nodes on a server and restart while tests would be pushed to the remaining servers. Then repeat the same process with scheduled jobs on the other servers.

Is there a way to shut down a selenium node once the current test finishes ? Or to get the status of a particular node so I can check each one myself in a scheduled job to make sure the node is not running a test before I shut it down ?

Answer (score 2):

You could check the number of active sessions by requesting each node with the `/sessions` command:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/sessions
```

Response :

```json
{"state":"success","sessionId":null,"hCode":3217742,"value":[],"class":"org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response","status":0}
```

Comment: Thank you. I seen this previously but thought it was a query on the hub and I was getting some errors when using it. Only after I see it here I realized it's used as http://<NodeIP>:<NodePort>/wd/hub/sessions.

Comment: Follow up question: I can see which nodes have active sessions using the command you mentioned. But when I try to shutdown the node using: http://node_ip_address:port/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer. The wait time between shutdown and being removed from use by the hub isn't fast enough to avoid new tests being allocated to that node. Do you know of a way to either speed up that process or actual unregistered a node instead of killing it and waiting for it to time out on the hub to get removed from the grid ?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to unregister a node by sending a command to the main hub.

Answer (score 1):

@Sh3mm

Sometime back I wrote up a blog post which basically talks about how to go about building a "Self Healing Grid" which is what you essentially are after.

You can read through my blog post on that from [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/building-a-self-maintaining-grid-environment/).

We essentially used the same approach when we working on building the SeLion Grid. The SeLion Grid packs in a few more sophistications. Read more about it [here](http://paypal.github.io/SeLion/html/documentation.html#selion-grid)

There's another flavor of essentially the same sort of functionalities that was built by GroupOn as part of their Grid Extras. You can take a look at it [here](https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras)

Comment: Thanks Krishnan, I did indeed come across that blog post but I wasn't sure if it was exactly what I was after. I have my hub and nodes installed using nssm to run as windows services. And part of what I want is to know when they aren't in use to restart the server not just the nodes. I wasn't sure if the Grid Extras is configurable as windows services or whether it was necessary to go all out and build a servlet. I was hoping to simply run a scheduled job to check if a node is in use, if not shut it down, once all nodes are shut down restart the server. Repeat this across the other machines

Comment: In your solution how do you deal with the fact that when the node is unregistered the hub doesn't immediately know and will keep trying to assign tests to it until it times out ?

Comment: @Sh3mm In that solution, the Grid also removes off the node from its registry when it is going to send a "kill" instruction. So the scenario that you call out will never happen.

Comment: Please include enough information in your answer that it is useful without the links, since the answer otherwise becomes useless if the target of the links goes away.

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut - The reason why I included my blog was because the concept by itself needs a bit of explanation and it would literally be duplicating my blog if i were to be copy pasting the contents. The other links are ofcourse from github

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan My comment stands - SO expects us to post answers that are helpful in and of themselves. While links to further information are perfectly fine, your answer has no useful information at all without the links.